# Subset specific rows in a dataframe, but keeping the observations

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, rows

I have a dataframe which look like this

```
y = data.frame(subdel = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 57, 14, 1, 2, 57, 57, 57, 3, 1, 1, 
  31, 21, 34, 56, 12, 45, 1, 63, 31, 34), muni =  c("A01",  "A83", "A40", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  "A45", "B26", "B42","B61", "B70", "B90", "C53", "C89","A45", "B26", "B42","B61", "B70"))
```

I'm expecting the next result:

```r
z = data.frame(subdel = c(1, 2, 3, 57, 57, 57, 57, 3, 1, 1, 31, 21, 34, 56, 12, 45, 1, 63, 31, 34), muni =  c("A01",  "A83", "A40", NA, NA, NA, NA,  "A45", "B26", "B42","B61", "B70", "B90", "C53", "C89", "A45", "B26", "B42","B61", "B70"))
```

I want to match `subdel == 57` with `muni == NA`, but, as you can see, conservating all the another observations in the dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `x == NA` will never give you what you want. `1==NA`, `NA==NA`, `"A"==NA` are all `NA`, not true or false. The canonical way to check for it is `is.na(muni)`.

Comment: You could create a key to match them by and then merge the vectors. With data.table it would be something like: 'setDT(subdel)[subdel==57, id:=1]' and 'setDT(muni)[is.na(muni), id:=1]' and 'merge(subdel, muni, all.x=T, all.y=T, by=c("id"))'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset` with a logical condition i.e. check for `NA` in 'muni' (`is.na(muni)`) and (`&`) where the 'subdel' is 57 (`subdel == 57`) or all other non-NA elements from 'muni' (`!is.na(muni)`)

```
subset(y, is.na(muni) & subdel == 57 | !is.na(muni))
```